# Dismiss Keyboard from TextField in a custom

Tags: xcode, uitextfield, uitableview

In the UITableViewController is using custom cells.  In the custom cell there is a TextField.  Need to dismiss the the keyboard when the user touches outside of the keyboard.  In the custom cell's .m file have added this code;

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [holeScoreTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

This does work for when the user touches another cell or inside the same cell.  Issue is that in the UITableViewController is a view with some information.  The above code does not work for that view.

Answer (score 1):

A very quick, dirty, and simple solution is to simply create a full screen sized invisible button over the entire screen. The keyboard will always appear over the top of that view.
Hide the view on `viewWillAppear:` and `textFieldShouldEndEditing:`, and show it on `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`.

Should work like a charm.